# Problems during the installation of python3.7 in centos

Tags: python, centos, installation

I have already installed the following package:

```
yum -y install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel libffi-devel
```

However, when i input

```
make && make install
```

the shell told me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I googled the solution is to install **libffi-devel**, but i have already installed it. 
Is there any step i made a mistake?

```
tar -zxvf Python-3.7.0.tgz
yum -y install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel libffi-devel
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3
make && make install
```

Comment: Do a `make clean` in the `Python-3.7.0` dir and try recompiling. Also, that error appears when you execute the compiled binary, not when you are still compiling, am I right?

Comment: @Alberto Chiusole sorry， i can't understand what you mean.Can you explain it more in detail. when I execute ```make```,there is no error. The error only occurs during the execution of  ```make install```.

Comment: I guess you installed `libffi` after your configure. Clean the directory you are compiling into and retry: `cd Python-3.7.0; make clean; ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3; make && make install`

Comment: PS: python 3.7.2 is available: https://www.python.org/downloads/